# configure openshift/origin with intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, openshift-origin

Has anyone had issues creating an IntelliJ project from existing sources for OpenShift/origin repo and getting all the godeps and libraries properly configured so there are no "missing reference" or "can not resolve" errors.

I added to the project library the path /origin/Godeps/_workspace/src which fixed many of the issues but wondering if that is what I should have done or if there is a better way? I also still see many unresolved errors.

The golang plugin SDK is version 1.5.3